# how to install BPEL in Helios eclipse without online? is there any other way than we have to write the address

Tags: bpel

I use Helios eclipse, but when installing BPEL by writing the address of the site a lot of problems. is there any manual way to install BPEL? what BPEL version is compatible with Helios?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the plugin manually and drop the jars under Eclipse plugins/ and features/ (if required) directories. This is what downloader does anyway.